# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in object Mapper

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

Hi I write the following code in json parsing my app is crashed when I am run with the error :

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

Find the code with following here model.orderID is type Int?

```
if let orderid = model.orderID
{
    cell.orderidlbl.text = String(orderid)
}
```

Comment: Does cell and its 'orderidlbl' exist at the time when this code is executed? 'orderidlbl' might be a candidate to be nil here.

Comment: I write this code in tableview. I call the api at view will appear method

Comment: put a check with label too like- if let orderid = model.orderID,let label = cell.orderidlbl { label.text = "updated value" }

Comment: On 'viewWillAppear' of view controller? How can the cell be instantiated at that point? You need to update the cell in cellForRow method of table view's data source.

Comment: yes I update that code in cell for row at index path only, I saying to I call api at view will appear.

Comment: are you sure you've connected outlet to `orderidlbl` in custom cell?

Comment: i almost want to bet its a callback problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I hope it helps you.

```
if let orderid = model.orderID as? Int
{
    cell.orderidlbl.text = String("\(orderid)")
}
```

Comment: set as optional type to model.orderID

Comment: String("\\(orderid)") this has no sense at all.